# Is this a bug? Angular removes object params when corresponding input is not valid

Tags: angularjs

Please see this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/soubKCayeLAqgDOel8AL?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="testCtlr">
    <pre>{{contacts | json}}</pre>
    <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <div ng-repeat="email in contact.emails">
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email.email">
        <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="email.text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testCtlr', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.contacts = [
        {
            id:'',
            name:'',
            emails:[
                {
                    email: 'e1',
                    text: 'fghfgh'
                },
                {
                    email: 'e2',
                    text: 'hjkhjk'
                }
            ],
        }
    ];
}]);
```

you see if you change the text in the email text box it is removed from the obj unless it is a valid email...

Answer (score 1):

Its not bug, its desired behaviourof angular, when value is not valid , it is not binded to ngModelController ,

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

But there is possibility to attach custom email validator ($parsers)
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers

You can push parser to array of parser so it will be executed as last, and return modelValue so you will "override" angular validator and bind invalidValue to ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, this is by design. The input type email uses regex to validate email address inputs. If the input is not valid it is removed from the model.

On another note - if you wrap your stuff in a form - you can determine the validation state of the inputs. Also, as you are using a repeat, you will need an index.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <div ng-repeat="email in contact.emails track by $index">
        <div ng-show="myForm.email{{$index}}.$invalid">Invalid email.</div>
        <input type="email" name="email{{$index}}" ng-model="email.email">
        <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="email.text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**I have updated your Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/P8vMjHBlwaMZoVdg66bj?p=preview).**

These are the validation states you can use:

```
//[formName].[inputFieldName].property 
myForm.email1.$pristine;
// Boolean. True if the user has not yet modified the form.
myForm.email1.$dirty
// Boolean. True if the user has already modified the form.
myForm.email1.$valid
// Boolean.True if the the form passes the validation.
myForm.email1.$invalid
// Boolean. True if the the form doesn't pass the validation.
myForm.email1.$error
```